Unable to install Express with npm because of local certification problem
I tried installing the express module with the command:
npm install express

But I get this error:
npm warn old lockfile   code: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY',
npm warn old lockfile   errno: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY',
npm warn old lockfile   type: 'system'
npm warn old lockfile }
npm warn old lockfile Could not fetch metadata for ini@1.3.5 FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/ini failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate

And it takes forever to load. Please help me if you've been through this or something similar.
I tried installing other packages such as lodash and got the same error. It seems I have a problem with certifications. But why would I need any certification to get a free package ?
I uninstalled node and then reinstalled so I have the latest version.
I tried disabling the SSL security with this command:
npm config set strict-ssl false

I also used:
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

But nothing seems to work. I tried everything chatGPT advised me to do but all my attempts were unsuccessful. I haven't found anyone on stack overflow with the same problem.

Can you delete the old lockfile?

Try using a different network OR clear the NPM cache and retry installing.  It might fix your problem

Thanks for answering. Tried both, it does not solve the problem.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
